# Can a Latin Hypercube Sampling design include constraints relating the variables?

Tags: experiment-design, latin-hypercube

I am trying to generate an experimental design using a Latin hypercube on three dimensions. I'm using MATLAB's lhsdesign(), but my question is about lhs sampling in general.

Two of my three variables, $A$ and $B$, are related such that $2A < B < 4A$. I'm uncertain whether it's even possible to do a proper LHS design in such a case, but whether it is or not, what would be an appropriate way to proceed and wind up with a space-filling design?

Comment: I think better split the task of space-filling and constraints for 1st investigations. One way to improve space-filling is optimization (e.g. using simulated annealing, that is slow but flexible). Or use e.g. orthogonal or near-orthogonal LHS methods (based on orthogonal maxtrices, fast but less flexible).

Comment: One option would be to proceed with your variables $A$, $B$, $C$ as usual, but set $f$ (the function you're trying to integrate) to zero for regions of parameter space where the constraint is violated. However, it would probably be more efficient to replace the $B$ variable with $\frac{B-2A}{4A}$; doing this gets you back to an unconstrained set of three variables.

Comment: Take a look at the article: ‘Latin hypercube sampling with inequality constraints’
Matthieu Petelet · Bertrand Iooss ⋆ · Olivier
Asserin · Alexandre Loredo